# Preventing a user's access to change a filter within a form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a form that searches for addresses. I set the form based on Criteria they enter in text boxes. I don't want them to be able to click on the Column heading in the results subform to change the filter. Is there a particular property that I can disable?

I know that disabling the entire form works fine but I need to allow them to click within the form, just not on the headings.

Answer (score 1):

Change the subform property Data->Allow Filters to `No`, it will prevent built-in filtering

Comment: The problem is that I want to allow filters that I define within the VBA event, I just don't want them to be able to click on the column header to change whatever that filter might be.

Comment: You will be able to filter the form using VBA. This flag just disables built-in shortcut menus for filtering. You also will be able to add your own popup menu with filtering options you want.